# MySQL SELECT COUNT with GROUP and ORDER performance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, count, group-by

The Facts:

- Dedicated Server, 4 Cores, 16GB
- MySQL 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.10.1-log - (Ubuntu)
- One Table, 1.9M rows and growing

I need all sorted rows for export or a 5er chunk. The query takes 25 seconds with Copying To Tmp Table 23.3 s

I tried InnoDB and MyISAM, changing the index order, using a MD5 Hash of `some_text` as GROUP BY, partition the table by `day`.

`day`is a Unix-Timestamp and alway present.
`lang` `some_bool` `some_filter` `ano_filter` `rel_id` could be in where clause but not need to.

Here is the MyISAM example:

The table

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE data \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: data
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `data_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `some_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `some_bool` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `some_filter` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ano_filter` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`data_id`),
  KEY `cnt_idx` (`some_filter`,`ano_filter`,`rel_id`,`lang`,`some_bool`,`some_text`,`day`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1900099 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `some_text` , COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM `data` 
 WHERE `lang` = 'en' AND `day` BETWEEN '1364342400' AND
 '1366934399' GROUP BY `some_text` ORDER BY `num` DESC \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: data
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: cnt_idx
      key_len: 947
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1900098
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> SELECT `some_text` , COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM `data` 
 WHERE `lang` = 'en' AND `day` BETWEEN '1364342400' AND '1366934399' 
 GROUP BY `some_text` ORDER BY `num` DESC LIMIT 5 \G;
...
*************************** 5. row ***************************
5 rows in set (24.26 sec)
```

Any idea how to speed up that thing?`

Answer (score 0):

No index is being used because of the column order in the index. Indexes work left to right. For this query to use an index, you would need an index of `lang, day`.

Comment: I added that index KEY `lang` (`lang`,`day`) but it isn't used at all: |1|SIMPLE|data|ALL|lang|NULL|NULL|NULL|1900098|Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort|

5 rows in set (27.51 sec)

Comment: I can't make out that gibberish.